# OpenERP - Rename Page String

Tags: xml, odoo, openerp-7

I'd like to rename the string of a page on OpenERP. To be specific, the 'Description' page on the Expenses module.

I'm not able to inherit this through the xpath code as the page itself has no name and you cannot change the label/string through the attrs fields. Below is the code I attempted to do this however it failed:

```
<xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[@string='Description']" position = "attributes">
        <attriute name = "string" = "Expenses"/>
</xpath>
```

There has to be a way to do this but I can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
<xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page[@string='Description']" position = "attributes">
    <attriute name = "string">Expenses</attriute>
</xpath>
```

For default attribute like

```
<xpath expr="path_of_field/page/group/whatever" position = "attributes">
    <attriute name = "attribute_name"> here is value </attriute>
</xpath>
```

Hope this will help you.